# Client applied to group policy object but cant find in WSUS

Tags: group-policy, wsus, groups

My client is `subscribed` to my group policy, But I cant find the computer in my WSUS when I look under `All Computers`. When I typed the command `gpresult /r` on my client it shows:

```
computer settings
-------------------
Applied Group Policy Objects
---------------------
     My own GPO
```

I checked my GPO and it is pointing to my WSUS (http://WSUS.local:8530).

Any ideas on what I forgot or possibly did wrong?

EDIT:
Also my wuauserv isnt running, when I type into cmd: `net start wuauserv` it gives this error:

```
System error 1058 has occurred

The service cannot be started, either because it is diabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.
```

After running `sfc /scannow` it didnt find any intergrity violations

I cant find my wuauserv.dll  in my system32 folder

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Somehow this fixed the problem (http://wuauclt.info/scripts.asp):

net stop bits 
net stop wuauserv 
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe %windir%\system32\vbscript.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe %windir%\system32\mshtml.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe %windir%\system32\msjava.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe %windir%\system32\jscript.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe %windir%\system32\msxml.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe %windir%\system32\actxprxy.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe %windir%\system32\shdocvw.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe wuapi.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe wuaueng1.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe wuaueng.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe wucltui.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe wups2.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe wups.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe wuweb.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe Softpub.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe Mssip32.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe Initpki.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe softpub.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe wintrust.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe initpki.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe dssenh.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe rsaenh.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe gpkcsp.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe sccbase.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe slbcsp.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe cryptdlg.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe Urlmon.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe Shdocvw.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe Msjava.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe Actxprxy.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe Oleaut32.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe Mshtml.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe msxml.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe msxml2.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe msxml3.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe Browseui.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe shell32.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe wuapi.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe wuaueng.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe wuaueng1.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe wucltui.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe wups.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe wuweb.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe jscript.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe atl.dll /s
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe Mssip32.dll /s 
net start bits 
net start wuauserv 
wuauclt /resetauthorization /detectnow